# Crash with this message: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.util.Date

Tags: android, android-studio

I am pretty new to android studio, and I was working on someone else's older project with firebase, and after updating to newer packages including firebase packages and migrating to androidx, I got the message

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

One such place where this occurs is a line like this:

```
Date lessonDate = course.lessonDates.get(i);
```

Another Stackoverflow answer suggested changing .get(i); to .getTimestamp(i).toDate(); but when I tried that, I got "Cannot resolve method getTimestamp(int). For clarity, an int is passed to get because it's an array from firebase. How can I resolve all of these Date problems?

Sorry if my terminology is incorrect, I am new to this.

Comment: What is your timestamp parameter's name? and how you code timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Firebase TimeStamp class has a toDate() method, which returns a Date type. This could probably solve your issue:

```
Date lessonDate = course.lessonDates.get(i).toDate();
```

Just use with caution, as it's mentioned in the docs that it may lose precision:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp.html#toDate()

Comment: When I do this, toDate is higlighted red "Cannot resolve method toDate"

Comment: What is "course.lessonDates.get(i)" returning? If toDate() cannot be resolved, it seems that this line of code is not returning a firebase Timestamp. Can you show some additional lines of code relevant to this line?

Comment: I believe the context is that I want to retrieve information from firebase about a lesson to display. So i have a for loop from 0 to course.lessons.size(); , and
      

Lesson lesson = course.lessons.get(i);
Date lessonDate = course.lessonDates.get(i);
Integer weekNumber = course.lessonWeekNumbers.get(i);
    

 and only the middle one returns that error